# How to get FID recognised by GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, fields-attributes, sld

I'm trying to load a shapefile into a GeoServer that has a style defined which makes use of the FID attribute:

```
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
       <Fill>
         <CssParameter name="fill">
           <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
             <!-- Property to transform -->
             <ogc:PropertyName>FID</ogc:PropertyName>
```

The shapefile I'm currently working with doesn't have an explicit 'FID' attribute:

```
$ ogrinfo -al -geom=NO precincts.dbf
...
OBJECTID: Integer (10.0)
Name: String (100.0)
Label: String (100.0)
Type: String (50.0)
CurrencyDa: Date (10.0)
SrcFormat: String (150.0)
Shape_area: Real (19.17)
Shape_len: Real (19.17)
```

But requesting the 'FID' attribute seems to somehow procure one:

```
$ ogrinfo -geom=NO -al precincts.shp -sql 'select FID from precincts'

FID: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(precincts):0
  FID (Integer) = 0

OGRFeature(precincts):1
  FID (Integer) = 1

OGRFeature(precincts):2
  FID (Integer) = 2
```

Uploading it to GeoServer however lists no FID attribute:
[image]

While other shapefiles previously uploaded (and whose provenance is unknown to me) do have one:

[image]

I have managed to generate one shapefile with a FID attribute by exporting it from PostGIS. However, this particular 'precincts' shapefile doesn't come from PostGIS. (Maybe I could import it to PostGIS just for this purpose, but that seems a bit dumb...)

Basically, I'm wondering:

1. What is the deal with the FID attribute? Is it a real attribute, or something that ogrinfo fakes?
2. Is there a way to turn it from a fake attribute into a real one so that GeoServer can see it?
3. Or is there some other way to get GeoServer to recognise it for the purposes of this style?

Comment: FID is an internal Feature ID that GDAL is using. From http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html `Normally the feature id is a special property of a feature and not treated as an attribute of the feature. In some cases it is convenient to be able to utilize the feature id in queries and result sets as a regular field. To do so use the name FID. The field wildcard expansions will not include the feature id, but it may be explicitly included using a syntax like: SELECT FID, * FROM nation`. So yes, it is something that ogrinfo fakes. Try ogrinfo with `-dialect sqlite`and it is not found.

Comment: If GeoServer shows FID in the attribute list it must come as a normal attribute from the .dbf file. You can probably rename the OBJECTID field into FID and reuse your SLD.

Comment: @user30184 You might want to post that as an answer :)

Comment: GeoServer will generate it's own FID when you import the shapefile but it will not be a simple integer.

Comment: @iant, you may confuse Steve. GeoServer generates FID for example with request http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=topp:states&maxfeatures=1 but it is still not the same as the "FID" in the second screen capture where FID is a normal attribute. I believe that using FID as an attribute name may lead to troubles sometimes, for example when trying to update FID (the attribute) with WFS-T 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments above I think I can answer now.

Shapefiles generally (always?) have an actual feature attribute, which may be called FID, OBJECTID or something else. But, perhaps because the name varies, the GDAL tools allow you to use the term 'FID' and they will generate a 'fake FID' on request, which may not match the actual feature identifier.

To turn a fake FID into a real FID is quite simple:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" precincts-fid.shp precincts.shp \
  -sql 'select FID,* from precincts'
```

This causes ogr2ogr to generate a row ID, and then save it alongside all the other actual attributes.

In case it's important to preserve another attribute as the FID (it wasn't in my case):

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" precincts-fid.shp precincts.shp \
  -sql 'select OBJECTID as FID,* from precincts'
```